# Install only part of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I currently have a large gem installed that I only use part of. So, a few questions:

- Is is possible to only install the part I need?
- If so, does that make more sense then installing the whole thing and only `require`ing the part I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible to install the gem in its entirety, i.e. everything declared in the gemspec.

> If so, does that make more sense then installing the whole thing and
>   only requireing the part I need?

Only requiring what you need is exactly what you're looking for. If the gem is declared in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "your_gem", require: false
```

Then, it won't be automatically required in your app and therefore, won't be loaded into memory, which seems to be the effect you want. Then, just require only the parts you need.